# Verifying Oracle 12 client server encryption

Tags: oracle, encryption

I'm getting conflicting information on whether encryption is active between my Oracle server and a Linux client:

```
SQL> select NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER from v$session_connect_info where SID = 
sys_context('USERENV','SID');   
NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------
TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Encryption service for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
RC4_40 Encryption service adapter for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 Production
Crypto-checksumming service for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
SQL>
```

Linux application server sqlnet.ora looks like below

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT = (SHA1) 
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT = required 
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (AES256) 
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = required
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=16
```

Server rebooted for good measure.

The traffic looks encrypted from a tcpdump's output, verified with wireshark:

```
tcpdump -n -A -vvv -i eth0 host client_IP and Oracle_server_IP -w ./output
```

Trace files (.trc) confirm the above too:

```
na_tns: Encryption is active, using AES256
```

Why is the NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER not reporting it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - My .bash_profile was referencing Oracle 11 and thus the wrong sqlnet.ora was being loaded.